# Saving array of images in core data as transformable

Tags: core-data, ios6.1

I want to add my imageArray into coredata as transformable but this is not storing properly.

My save button coding.

```
  - (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FoodInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSAttributeDescription *messageType = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
[messageType setName:@"photos"];
[messageType setAttributeType:NSTransformableAttributeType];
[imagesForShow addObject:messageType];
 NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to save context for class" );
} else {
    NSLog(@"saved all records!");
    [context save:nil];
}
//[newEntry setValue:imagesForShow forKey:@"images"];


}
```

- Here 'imagesForShow' is my array of images.

When iam going to fetch this image array , this showing nil

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"FoodInfo"];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
arrayForPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]];




// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

What  I am doing wrong with this code. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the attribute description? Where is the array configured? What error / result do you see? Why store the images in core data?

Comment: This is the description about image array. error is nothing but this is showing nil when I am going to fetch. I want images in future that I am selecting from photo library.  If there is any other method by which i can store image array in core data than please post.

Comment: If they're in the photo library why don't you store the asset URLs?

Answer (score 0):

In your save code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newEntry = [NSEntityDescription
     insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FoodInfo"
     inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSAttributeDescription *messageType = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
[messageType setName:@"photos"];
[messageType setAttributeType:NSTransformableAttributeType];
[imagesForShow addObject:messageType];
```

I can't even figure out what this is supposed to do. It's completely wrong. You should never be allocating an instance of `NSAttributeDescription` unless you are constructing a Core Data model on the fly-- which you are not doing and which almost nobody ever does. Creating the new entry is OK. The rest, I don't know. You said that `imagesForShow` is your array of images, so I don't know why you're also adding an attribute description to the array.

In a more general sense, **if** `newEntry` has a transformable attribute named `photos` **and** `imagesForShow` is an `NSArray` of `UIImage` objects, then you could do this:

```
[newEntry setValue:imagesForShow forKey:@"photos"];
```

This is similar to a line that you have commented out, though it's not clear why it's commented out.

But whatever you do get rid of the code creating the `NSAttributeDescription`.